# Ctr + click not working in ie11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I have written a small java script code which replaces the url for anchor tags with valid url on go. Code for my listener

```
document.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
        // Some code to here
        };
```

I have bind the EventListener on click which does some work. Its working fine with other browser, but when i do ctr + click in ie11 /edge its not firing the listener. It does the  normal redirect as per the url in anchor tag. Can anyone suggest where i am  going wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is because it opens the link in a new window. The click()-event also does not capture right-click and then choosing "open in new tab".

What you could try is to go with the jquery-event .mousedown() which should catch the event I think.

http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/

Once you caught the event you stop the original action that would be  executed by evt.preventDefault() and then manage the redirect yourself.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but i have already tried 'mousedown' event . Still no luck

Comment: Do you mean it does not fire at all? If the event fires before the redirect (which it should) you can prevent the default action and execute your own javascript instead.

Comment: it does fire the event but , redirect goes to default url, but not on the replaced url

Comment: Could you add your code for redirection in your eventhandler to your question? Maybe there is something to fix. If you use evt.preventDefault() in the beginning to stop the original action triggered by the event you should be able to do the redirect yourself.